# Varargs function argument of generic partial application does not type check

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples, variadic-functions, partial-application

I have the following combinator that converts a mutli-argument function in one that can be partially applied:

```
type Tuple = any[];

const partial = <A extends Tuple, B extends Tuple, C>
  (f: (...args: (A & B)[]) => C, ...args1: A) => (...args2: B) =>
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    f(...args1, ...args2);

const sum = (v: number, w: number, x: number, y: number, z: number) =>
  w + w + x + y + z;

partial(sum, 1, 2, 3)(4, 5);
//      ^^^
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANtAvFAhgOxAbQLoDcAsAFBTlSkDGA9pgM7BRjoBOwAluolGgDwBBKBAAewCJgAm9WAmQAaKACFhYidNlIIigMIA+UhSgAKAGYAuEwDobbAOb1LxoQDJlASnzveeqDsU2Vvb0AIyWAt4ovsaBwQBMlkqRBmRGFKYxtqwOIQFZDnHuxKnk1HSMUPRwALa8JgBulpg1AEYQrIoA7k2t7YoiPdVtHVAgg8OKAF7j7clQnVAA1PNLUCKrIKuTxUakLOxciMZV1Yq5UHGKAMzuxgAsigCsRUA)

This doesn't work, because the function argument `f` must accept various numbers of arguments without using rest syntax. Is there a way to type `f`?

Comment: You can't concatenate tuple types by intersecting them.  For example, `[string, number] & [boolean]` is not equivalent to `[string, number, boolean]`.  Instead it's an impossible tuple whose `length` is the uninhabitable type `1 & 2`, and whose first element is the uninhabitable type `string & boolean`.  There's no built-in tuple concatenation at the type level (see [microsoft/TypeScript#5453](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)) and the workarounds come in various flavors of ugly and unsupported. 

Comment: I figured that.. I guess from a type level perspective rest syntax is mainly useful if it yields an array `A[]` instead of a tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't concatenate tuple types by intersecting them. For example, `[string, number] & [boolean]` is not equivalent to `[string, number, boolean]`. Instead it's an impossible tuple whose `length` is the uninhabitable type `1 & 2`, and whose first element is the uninhabitable type `string & boolean`. There's no built-in tuple concatenation at the type level (see [microsoft/TypeScript#5453](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453)) and the workarounds come in various flavors of ugly and unsupported.

Here's a workaround that's somewhat ugly and possibly unsupported (although see [microsoft/TypeScript#32131](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32131) which will introduce new typings for [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) that do pretty much the same thing):

```
type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
type Tail<T extends any[]> = 
  ((...t: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...t: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
type Drop<T extends any[], N extends number> = 
  { 0: T, 1: Drop<Tail<T>, Prev[N]> }[N extends 0 ? 0 : 1];

const partial = <
    X extends any[],
    Y extends Extract<{ [K in keyof Y]: K extends keyof X ? X[K] : never }, any[]>,
    R>(
        f: (...args: X) => R,
        ...args1: Y
    ) => (...args2: Drop<X, Y['length']>): R => f(...[...args1, ...args2] as any);
```

The type `Prev` is just a tuple that lets you get from one number to the previous number, up to whatever limit you want.  So `Prev[4]` is `3` and `Prev[3]` is `2`.

The type `Tail<T>` takes a tuple type `T` and strips off the first element, leaving everything after.  So `Tail<[1, 2, 3, 4]>` is `[2, 3, 4]`.

The type `Drop<T, N>` is the possibly-unsupported recursive thing that takes a tuple type `T` and a number `N` and strips off the first `N` elements, leaving everything after.  So `Drop<T, 1>` is basically just `Tail<T>`, and `Drop<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2>` is `[3, 4, 5]`.

Finally, the `partial()` signature is generic in tuple type `X`, corresponding to the full set of arguments for `f`, and a tuple type `Y`, corresponding to the rest of the arguments to `partial()`, and `Y` must be some initial segment of `X`. So if `x` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`, then `Y` can be `[1]`, or `[1, 2]`, ...  or `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.  And the type `R` is the return type of `f`.  Then, it returns a new function whose return type is `R`, and whose argument type is `Drop<X, Y['length']>`.  That is, the returned function accepts the arguments to `f` *after* the ones in `Y`.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
const sum = (v: number, w: number, x: number, y: number, z: number) => v + w + x + y + z;

const okay = partial(sum, 1, 2, 3); // const okay: (y: number, z: number) => number
console.log(okay(4, 5)) // 15

const bad = partial(sum, "a", "b", "c"); // error "a" is not number
const alsoBad = partial(sum, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // error 6 is not never
```

Looks good to me.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBACgThAblAvFA2gOyROAaKABgIEYCAmAgZgIBYCBWAgNgIHYCAOAgTlOKgkSAXQDcAWABQoSFAAqAQwCWAGwA8cqBAAewCJgAmAZygLMIdMIB8qKAAo7AOmfAAXPICUqG4gD2Sgy8dPUMTBwALdzMQAmdHNyglTAAzXCgAJS8UH39AqAB+DKh3bERcCWlwaAAROF8wDS1dfWNTc0sCADkmkNbMAFcAWwAjXBs0AG8idzlSd1r6jWV1OSsCeCR0TusoAF8tnpaTQgKiYsExKSkAY19MI2AoMAU4YCUFFVs1KShfqAANQ6hNoWYR4H5-ACaQNaAFFdHAFNdgGopugANKJTBQADWEBAvmSUEhwncmOCR1x+MJANO-wxwnOpTSuwI0Usawhv3SVjsXL+v2S7iczheAHMjO5-lkbOlwZIBQK4uKjCR3JD+TL7Mq4BLyPM6g1-gRIegAOQqfRi4DhM3WDzudLeKDJEWOdA6iVkKCeozkRkKEzRDwVK6SW73R5GIa2OyIEpDUb4KAAdwTI1wBG06aTBBAOczUAAXgW4FrkABqVNQKvaGtQED1ouh8N3B5QXw4hSNtDPV7vFR2aODUgUaghqAAeknUAj7c73eF+agAwzyZLK8TuC1q6TNzbvktjhUvjFdgXIDs9CgDA8XmnggYYbnj2GCgMtj7bw+Q6GBAARAo-4AcMwFQP+1z-hOD64HUcDgUBiQmJgviPLuuD7pGpgqEYvgAELvp+LzfoOw6jlAlBQDQUDXkwUDMNBM6wb48HMEhK6oSuOBwGGYZQEAA)

Comment: This is like type level programming.